# Referencing Associated Object Returns Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, associations

I have two models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :message
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

If I have a created user with an associated `Message` and I delete that message and create a new one like, `user.message` returns nil. For example.

```
user = User.create

message = Message.create(user_id: user.id)

Message.where(user_id: user.id).destroy_all

Message.create(user_id: user.id)

# Now if I call this below, it always returns nil
user.message
```

Why does this occur? Shouldn't Rails 3 pick up on that change? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load the object again before doing `user.message` like, `user.reload`.

[`reload`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-reload) - Reloads the record from the database.